# missing ziphash error while importing local module with Go modules

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm trying to import a local module as follows:

```
module my_module

go 1.13

require nimbus v0.0.0

replace nimbus => ../../nimbus
```

The IDE (I'm working with Goland) is able to find the package as expected and importing features from the module nimbus works as expected, but, when running the command

```
go mod verify
```

This error occurs:

```
nimbus v0.0.0: missing ziphash: open hash: no such file or directory
```

The local package I'm trying to import has a go.mod file as follows:

```
module nimbus

go 1.13

require (
    cloud.google.com/go/firestore v1.2.0
    firebase.google.com/go v3.13.0+incompatible
    golang.org/x/sync v0.0.0-20200317015054-43a5402ce75a
    google.golang.org/api v0.25.0
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.29.1
)
```

I could not find an explanation for this error by Googling it.

Comment: Might be related to `v0.0.0`, it's not a version liked in general.

Comment: @ferhatelmas by doing go mod tidy it changes the version to nimbus v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000 but the problem remains the same

Comment: https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/vgo/+/121659/2/vendor/cmd/go/vgo_test.go according to this comment, it will fail with explict verify call since it's not published so no ziphash from proxy and this check is skipped for a regular build (tidy/download etc.)

Comment: This is probably a bug in the `go` command. If you can still reproduce it using `go1.16rc1`, please open an issue at https://golang.org/issue/new.

Comment: On go 1.16, running `go clean --modcache` and then running `go mod verify` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Is there any workaround here?